# What would be the Russian term for cruising in your car listening to music? Also,Is there a term when the mob travel and drive as a group?

Tags: одним-словом

Is there a term for driving and listening to music with no destination just to drive listening to music? Is there a specific term to drive and listen to music at night? Is there a term when a large group of cars cruise together mob or civilian?

Comment: And what would be the English term for exactly the same activity? :)

Comment: or any other language except English?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a term when a large group of cars cruise together mob or civilian?

In the formal and official context the term is "**автоколонна**". It is an organized group of buses / trucks / cars / military vehicles, accompanied by the police. This word is, e.g., for moving large group of workers from one site to another, or transporting a large group of schoolchildren to their summer camp. A motorcade. It's definitely not for "driving with no particular destination listening to music".

For informal context the term is "**покатушка**". This word is often used when a large group of people go biking, cycling, or roller skating. But there are examples when it's used in the context of a group driving their cars around for pleasure, for example, a group of off-road fans driving to a particularly attractive dirt hole.

Comment: never heard покатушка, probably it's biker(cycler) jargon, but the general population may not know it

Comment: @alexsms: Can't say for sure, but it certainly appears in an official [dictionary](http://orfo.ruslang.ru/abc/part/pe?start=112227&end=112527). And it seems that the dictionary suggests pluralia tantum.

Comment: @alexsms I've personally heard it a lot.

Comment: i see, my guess is that it's slang among car, bike enthusiasts

Comment: "покатушки" - sounds rather childish\girlish too.

Comment: i'm familiar with the word, but would never use it myself, to me it sounds cringey

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any particular exact word for this. However if someone have asked me to describe this in Russian I'd rather used something like:

> Кружить по району без дела и слушать музыку.

or

> Просто кататься и слушать музыку.

There's no verb like "слоняться" or "бродить [без дела]" but for driving, so this is the closest I can think of.